# Get value from Dropdown in PHP with onchange event

Tags: php, selectedtext

Good morning everyone !

Here's the situation; I have 2 dropdownlists, the first one contains some informations.. 
the second one, contains names of some people.

They both are filled from database.

What I want to do, is when a name is selected in the second Dropdownlist, i want automaticly to trigger a function that updates the 1st dropdownlist, using the selected text of 2nd dropdownlist in the WHERE clause of SQL Query..

I can do this in JAVA or .NET languages, but i'm new in PHP..

So can you please help me ?

Comment: Have you never worked with javascript/Jquery in .Net or JAVA before?

Comment: You need to research XMLHTTPRequest (XHR) with Javascript in order to acheive that. List updates are a common case and you'll find many tutorials for this kind of stuff on the internet

Comment: @asprin; no, i always worked in desktop application.. (vb.net, c#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very good tutorial for same

http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/en/how-to-create-chained-select-with-php-and-jquery/

LoneWOLFs is right. its not possible using php only, to trigger onChange you will required javascript

Comment: its working here, you can try in different browser here is example page http://www.yourinspirationweb.com/example/maurizio/select_en/select.php

Comment: copy and paste link in address bar, don't click on link they are not accepting referee

Answer (score 0):

For PHP you will have to use javascript to trigger an event on the 2nd dropdownlist.  You can't do this with PHP alone.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer